# Issue rendering individual items from an array collection on a view in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Am working on a Laravel application whereby I have some data in an array collection,, I am trying to display the data on teh view using a foreach loop. Am trying to reach out to the id of each array in the collection and display on the view dynamically. For instance if there are 4 arrays it should display 4 ids on the view.

The problem is that after the foreach loop I only get one id instead of the 4 ids.

**Array Collection I have and is stored in a variable called asm**

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => "157"
    "unit_sales_managers" => array:7 [▶]
    "policies" => array:3007 [▶]
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => "73401"
    "unit_sales_managers" => array:8 [ …8]
    "policies" => array:2226 [ …2226]
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => "0"
    "unit_sales_managers" => array:1 [ …1]
    "policies" => array:162 [ …162]
  ]
  3 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => "76300"
    "unit_sales_managers" => array:1 [ …1]
    "policies" => array:1 [ …1]
  ]
]
```

**Foreach loop on the blade**

```
//Loop through all the arrays
@foreach ($asm as $r)
<div class="panel-group" id="hierachy">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1"> {{ dd($r['id']) }}</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">Panel Body</div>
      <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: can you dump $asm in view and also check page source is there any css issue???

Comment: @Shibon What do you mean by CSS issue ??

Comment: please press ctrl+u in browser and see if id is present in source code of html

Comment: @Marin Please check this urls
https://codepen.io/wizly/pen/BlKxo
<br>
https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/panels-with-nav-tabs 
And see ur code............................

Comment: You use `{{ dd($r['id']) }}` in your code, which stops execution. Replace with `{{ $r['id'] }}`

Comment: @kerbholz Ohh Men,, Sure never noticed it thanks alot,,it works fine now

Comment: Nice, glad it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are using `{{ dd($r['id']) }}` (dd="dump and die()") which stops execution of your script. Replace this with just `{{ $r['id'] }}` to display the value and continue in your `foreach`-loop.

More on `dd()`: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-dd

Comment: Sure,, was a very silly mistake on my side,, thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
@foreach ($asm as $asms)
      @foreach ($asms as $r)
         <?php
             print('<pre style="color:red;">');
             print_r($r);
             print('</pre>');
             exit;
         ?>
         <div class="panel-group" id="hierachy">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1"> {{ dd($r['id']) }}</a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">Panel Body</div>
              <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: @Shibon: sorry please check now

Comment: @SaurabhDhariwal Tried your code and I get error of **Illegal string offset id**

Comment: @Martin: please display result of `$r` as per my updated answer